# Super type initialization is impossible without primary constructor in android kotlin mvvm

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

**What i am trying to do:**

I am trying to link viewModel into activity and use a factory in between

In the **MainActivity.kt**

```
KtMainActivityViewModelFactory    ktMainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,ktMainActivityViewModelFactory).get(KtMainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

**KtMainActivityViewModelFactory.kt**

```
class KtMainActivityViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {


    private val movieRepository: MovieRepository
    private val database: MoviesAppDatabase
    private val dataservice: MovieDataService

    @Inject
    constructor(movieRepository: MovieRepository, database: MoviesAppDatabase, dataservice: MovieDataService) {
        this.movieRepository = movieRepository
        this.database = database
        this.dataservice = dataservice
    }


    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return KtMainActivityViewModelFactory(movieRepository, database, dataservice) as T
    }


}
```

**KtMainActivityViewModel.kt**

```
class KtMainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {


    private val movieRepository: MovieRepository
    private val database: MoviesAppDatabase
    private val dataservice: MovieDataService


    constructor(movieRepository: MovieRepository, database: MoviesAppDatabase, dataservice: MovieDataService) : super() {
        this.movieRepository = movieRepository
        this.database = database
        this.dataservice = dataservice
    }


}
```

**Error:**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have only one constructor, it should be made primary:

```
class KtMainActivityViewModel(private val movieRepository: MovieRepository, private val database: MoviesAppDatabase, private val dataservice: MovieDataService) : ViewModel() { ... }
```

As an extra benefit, this way you also need to mention each property once instead of 4 times.

Note that you *could* declare `private val movieRepository: MovieRepository` etc. in body

```
class KtMainActivityViewModel(movieRepository: MovieRepository, database: MoviesAppDatabase, dataservice: MovieDataService) : ViewModel() { 
    private val _movieRepository: MovieRepository = movieRepository
    ...
}
```

but there's no reason to.

Of course this also applies to `KtMainActivityViewModelFactory`:

```
class KtMainActivityViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val movieRepository: MovieRepository, private val database: MoviesAppDatabase, private val dataservice: MovieDataService) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return KtMainActivityViewModelFactory(movieRepository, database, dataservice) as T
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class KtMainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {


private lateinit var movieRepository: MovieRepository
private lateinit var database: MoviesAppDatabase
private lateinit var dataservice: MovieDataService


constructor(movieRepository: MovieRepository, database: MoviesAppDatabase, dataservice: MovieDataService) : super() {
    this.movieRepository = movieRepository
    this.database = database
    this.dataservice = dataservice
    }
 }
```

You should add primary constructor and replace `super()` to `this()`

```
class KtMainActivityViewModel(): ViewModel() {
```

Comment: This won't compile because properties aren't initialized.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov he has only asked to get rid of that error, also corrected that

Answer (score 1):

try changing it to `KtMainActivityViewModel : ViewModel`